# Construct JSON object from javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
var jsonArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    jsonArr.push({
         id: i,
         optionValue: "abc"
    });
}
jsonArr = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
console.log(jsonArr);
```

This code gives me following output:

```
[{"id":0,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":1,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":2,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":3,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":4,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":5,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":6,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":7,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":8,"optionValue":"abc"},{"id":9,"optionValue":"abc"}]
```

But I need

```
[{id:0,optionValue:"abc"},{id:1,optionValue:"abc"},{id:2,optionValue:"abc"},{id:3,optionValue:"abc"},{id:4,optionValue:"abc"},{id:5,optionValue:"abc"},{id:6,optionValue:"abc"},{id:7,optionValue:"abc"},{id:8,optionValue:"abc"},{id:9,optionValue:"abc"}]
```

This output,

I searched through Google, But it says `ParameterName` without double quotes is not valid.

But I need this output only, Any help from you friends?

Comment: The first one a valid JSON object (a serialized JS object), while what you're looking for is a JS object.
If you need to send it thought the network, use the JSON then use the `JSON.parse` to have the JS equivalent object.

Comment: Why do you need invalid JSON? I'm not aware of anywhere that the second syntax (which can be valid JavaScript) is OK but the JSON syntax is not.

Comment: @MarcoCI No friend, I need without quotes, ie. `"id"` should be `id`

Comment: Don't stringify it and you have what you want.

Comment: You requires something that is *not* a JSON string. Seems you have to make a custom serializer.

Comment: For one chart I have to pass this types value only, If I pass with quotes its not working.

Comment: The JSON syntax standard is not dependent on your need. If you stringify it, no matter how hard you crush your head it's still going to be `"id"`, not `id`. If you need something like that, you have to manually replace the `"` yourself with a string replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 $(function () {
        var jsonArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            jsonArr.push({
                id: i,
                optionValue: "abc"
            });
        }
        jsonArr = JSON.stringify(jsonArr).replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g, "$1:");
        console.log(jsonArr);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that what you need is stringified native JS object, I wrote a simple serializer. It may require thorough tests before using this in a production environment.

```
var jsStringify = function (obj) {
    var out = "";
    if (typeof obj == "object") {
        // object
        if (typeof obj.length == "undefined") {
            out += "{";
            var idx = 0;
            for (var n in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                    out += (idx > 0) ? "," : "";
                    out += n + ":" + jsStringify(obj[n]);
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            out += "}";
        }
        // array
        else {
            out += "[";
            var idx = 0; 
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    out += (idx > 0) ? "," : "";
                    out += jsStringify(obj[i]);
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            out += "]";
        }
    } else {
        out += JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
    return out;
}

jsStringify([{
    id: "test",
    no: 1,
    nested: [1, [2, "3", {
        inline: ["\"double-quote-safe\""]
    }], 4]
}]);
```

The output:

```
[{id:"test",no:1,nested:[1,[2,"3",{inline:["\"double-quote-safe\""]}],4]}]
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SbWtN/

Btw, simply regex-replacing could do the work if values do not contain any *double-quote* characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  array.push({
     id: i,
     optionValue: "abc"
  });
}
console.log(array);
```